# Ruby - Bundle Install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, edx, openedx

I am a novice in Ruby and I am trying to follow some instruction. The instructions are as follows:

1 Install Ruby and RVM

2 I installed ruby from apt-get and rvm from

```
curl -sL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
```

3 I add the source by

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

4. I installed `rvm install 1.9.3-p374`

5.And then I did `rvm use "1.9.3-p374@edx-platform" --create`

6 And then I did `rvm rubygems latest` and `gem install bundler`

7 But as soon as I do `bundle install --gemfile Gemfile`

I get an error saying `/root/edx_all/edx-platform/Gemfile not found`

The instructions are to install OpenEdx on Ubuntu 12.04 and are given here - 
[Installation Instruction for OpenEdx](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzttDZjI_OAhXEO48KHQ_jBgoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.it.iitb.ac.in%2Ffrg%2Fbrainstorming%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2FEDX-Manual%2520Install%2520behind%2520proxy.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGV2tAFzkfueEcMm9FoOFTMmuLbJw&sig2=EAThkOWda1fSNcA5OVgXog)

Please help me out by pointing what I am doing wrong

Comment: When you run `bundle install`, you need to make sure there is a `Gemfile` present in your working directory.

Comment: How can i add this Gemfile.

Comment: I am trying to follow the instructions given in the link and they are supposed to be complete step by step process.
And there is no mention about this Gemfile

Comment: @NishantDixit you should read yor instruction carefully http://imgur.com/a/BFOnC

Comment: @Зелёный  I'm doing exactly that. But the bundle install step is not working. Please help